Set POJO field value based on the value of another field in Spring Boot
I have a simple POJO class
class POJO{
private boolean isEnabled,
private String field
}

I have a controller that accepts RequestBody of type POJO, as part of a change I want to include a validation such that when isEnabled is true in the RequestBody set the value of field to "TEST" (value of field in RequestBody will be null) and when isEnabled is false set the value of field to value received from RequestBody
I can implement a if...else... on the controller/service but this involves a lot of code replication especially since i have multiple fields to set, Is there a way i can incorporate this validation within the POJO class itself?

You just need to put the logic in the dto constructor.
class POJO {
  private boolean isEnabled,
  private String field;

  public POJO (boolean isEnabled, String field) {
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    this.field = isEnabled ? "TEST" : field;
  }
} 


This can be a solution but making an explicit call to the POJO constructor in the controller does not seem like a good design to me especially since my RequestBody is already of type POJO

Why explicit? Spring Web calls the constructor itself when mapping object. You don't do anything for this in the controller

I am making use of Lombok in my POJO class and i have multiple other fields present in the POJO class not dependent on any other fields if i create a constructor with signature public POJO (boolean isEnabled, String field) i would have to make an explicit call in the controller , since i am calling this over the lomboks constructor.

Lombok is cool and @AllArgsConstructor is cool, but you need to keep in mind the java mechanisms. If you have multiple fields, then just put them in constructor public POJO (boolean isEnabled, String field, String field1, String field1, ...) and just this.field1 = field1; etc. and only on this.field = isEnabled ? "TEST" : field;. I think this logic should be placed in the constructor, but better in the business logic of @Service. Sorry me if I don't fully understand you.

Based on question description

when isEnabled is true in the RequestBody set the value of field to
"TEST" (value of field in RequestBody will be null)

getField(){
    return this.field == null && this.isEnabled? "TEST" : this.field.
}

You just need to make sure that you are not accessing field in any other way except getter.
Other funny options:

Fast but error prone and I would not use it on production:

public void setField(String field) {
    this.field = isEnabled ? "TEST" : field;
}

Whenever jackson maps json string to java object it calls setters(if they are present). This one will work only if jackson object mapper DEserializes isEnabled field before field field. So,
works
"{\"isEnabled\":true,\"field\":\"fieldVal\"}"

doesn't work
"{\"field\":\"fieldVal\",\"isEnabled\":true}"


You could use spring filter and add it to your controller methods. So your code will reside only in one place and there won't be any code duplication
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-request-body-before-controller
Create custom object mapper serializer/deserializer, it will give you full control over how json is mapped into java object
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization
Use AOP on controller method, aspect will work like an invisible wrapper around your method, so you will get access to RequestBody object before actual
controller method https://medium.com/trabe/cleaner-spring-mvc-controllers-using-aop-and-filters-41c89ac4f9d

Requirement looks a little bit unusual and it would be nice to know why would you like to have such kind of a thing at all. There are a lot of ways how to achieve it and having a better context of the problem you are trying to solve will definitely help to chose the right one.
